# What is the right way to prevent out of memory exception with StreamReader.ReadToEnd()?

Tags: c#, validation, .net-core, fortify

I'm reading a text file using Stream reader ReadToEnd() method like so:

```
        private string GetCSSReset()
        {
            var assembly = typeof(EmailSender).GetTypeInfo().Assembly;
            using (var stream = EmbeddedScriptsProvider.ReadInternal(assembly, GlobalVars.CSSFileName))
            {
                using (var textReader = new StreamReader(stream))
                {
                    var text = textReader.ReadToEnd();
                    return $"{text}";
                }
            }

        }
```

However it has been flagged on a Fortify SCA scan that this might lead to a Denial of Service attack.

I have modified `EmbeddedScriptsProvider.ReadInternal()` to do a check on the stream length

```
        internal static long MBtoContentLength(int megaByte)
        {
            return megaByte * 1024 * 1024;
        }
        internal static Stream? ReadInternal(Assembly assembly, string resource)
        {
            var stream = assembly.GetManifestResourceStream($"{assembly.GetName().Name}.{resource}");
            if(stream.Length > MBtoContentLength(GlobalVars.MAX_FILE_SIZE_MB))
            {
                throw new InvalidOperationException("File size too large.");
            }
            return stream;
        }
```

Is this the right way to handle the issue? I've seen other methods where they used `.Read()` and checked the string length, how do I apply that for `ReadToEnd()` ?

Comment: Are you reading an internal file deployed with the application? If so, the only DDOS risk is created internally, which you can usually ignore as there's bigger issues at play if there is a internal malicious actor.

Comment: Since you're reading the stream from your own assembly (rather than from a user-supplied file), I don't see how this could be used for a DOS attack. Looks like a false positive to me.

Comment: Thanks, will raise this with the SA. Appreciate the input